# I would like to buy a Torah scroll in order to host Shabbat services in my home. What should I know and how much should I expect to spend?

Tags: sefer-torah

It's something that's not immediate because I don't have the space nor the money but I'd like to one day. What would the process be like and how much should I expect to spend?

Comment: You are looking to spend 30-50 thousand dollars US. Also it depends on if a sofer will sell it to you based on your Jewish status and what level of observance you and your congregation will be doing. You can buy a silk screened torah but many Rabbis reject them. You can find out silk screen printed torahs here: http://kashrut.org/scrollproject/

Comment: Curious - Do you live far away from a shul that it is wortwhile to spend the money to have  services in your home?

Comment: It's nothing right away, just wondering what it would be like in the future if it ever made sense to do so. Just very curious!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example, you can buy a kosher sefer torah [Buying a Sefer Torah](http://www.tiferes.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=8)

> Price categories vary from $24,000 - $55,000; the cost is determined
>   by the consistency and beauty of the Ktav(script). All of our Torah
>   Scrolls are 100% Kosher and acceptable irrelevant of price. The
>   materials used in the Sefer Torah – Klaf (parchment) and ink are the
>   best available in Israel today. The Price of the Sefer Torah includes
>   all necessary inspections and proof reading with a final inspection by
>   computer. Your Sefer Torah is guaranteed to be 100% kosher and fit for
>   use.

You also need to get an aron kodesh, have a proper room to keep it in and, given that you want to have services, you would need to build rooms that can have a proper mechitzah and sufficient seforim (at least siddurim and chumashim) for the people.

You would also need multiple sifrei Torah for days on which one must lein from multiple sifrei torah or to avoid having to roll to Rosh Chodesh and back to the shabbos parsha.

You would be better off lending a sefer torah to a shul that has the proper facilities.

Comment: It would be nice to honour the Sefer Torah with ornaments, normally silver. These would be in addition to the price range quoted.

Comment: Mostly excellent answer, but you do not NEED multiple scrolls for certain holidays.  At my Orthodox shul, we roll it to the required place for reading.  Not as convenient maybe, but totally legit if that is what your budget dictates.

Comment: @Mike true. it is a suggestion in order to avoid tircha detziburah and is a "better" way of handling things if it is possible. Also it helps save wear and tear on the sefer torah.